# How do I update the args for a Kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a deployment running in Kubernetes and want to update the "args" prior to applying an update so that when it restarts, it uses a different entrypoint arg than it did during its initial startup, which also included some data bootstrapping.

I know you can run `kubectl set image` to update the image that the deployment or replicaset is running, but how can I also update the args without deleting and re-creating the resource?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`kubectl patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) as pointed in the answer by @mr.franco. I'm using this to patch `args` of `kubernetes-dashboard` Deployment without modifying their official installation manifest.

Here is a full example of how you can replace (in terms of JSON patch) container `args` on existing Deployment:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.1/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

```sh
kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace kubernetes-dashboard -o=json | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args'
```

```
[
  "--auto-generate-certificates",
  "--namespace=kubernetes-dashboard"
]
```

```sh
kubectl patch deployment \
  kubernetes-dashboard \
  --namespace kubernetes-dashboard \
  --type='json' \
  -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args", "value": [
  "--auto-generate-certificates",
  "--enable-insecure-login",
  "--enable-skip-login",
  "--namespace=kubernetes-dashboard"
]}]'
```

```sh
kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace kubernetes-dashboard -o=json | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].args'
```

```
[
  "--auto-generate-certificates",
  "--enable-insecure-login",
  "--enable-skip-login",
  "--namespace=kubernetes-dashboard"
]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to append to the existing argument list (and not replace it completely), you could also use the `add` jsonpatch operation. For example, I needed to add `--enable-ssl-passthrough` to my running nginx controller for ArgoCD to work correctly:

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx patch deployment ingress-nginx-controller \
--type=json \
-p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-", "value": "--enable-ssl-passthrough"}]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply, do `kubectl edit deployment/<deployment-name>` ([see docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-edit)), modify the `args` field of your container spec, and save+quit from your `$EDITOR`.

This will update the deployment spec "in place" and delete and restart your pods with the new arguments. Under the hood this is no different from deleting and restarting your pods.

Comment: This would work for manually managing the cluster, but I'm looking to script it such that a "restart" script would update the arg to a new value, scale the deployment to 0, then back up to 1.

Comment: In that case, you can simply do a `kubectl replace -f deployment.yaml` after generating a new one with the required arg in the spec? Does that work for you? If you want to script it you can template the deployment.yaml with either helm or jinja2 (cli tools available).

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`kubectl patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) for that use case.

For reference you can check [that](https://serverfault.com/a/925027) answer.

Comment: Would be great if you could write out the command; it's not just to "check the answer" since that answer doesn't update the args field.